# My dishwasher is too short for the counter

Tags: dishwasher, cabinets

We just remodeled our kitchen and the cabinet opening is 35 inches high but newly bought dishwasher is only 31.5 inches. How can I properly install it with the height difference?

Comment: adjustable feet ????

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you got about 3.5" to make up.  I'd put a couple of 2x4s front to back stacked flat and screwed down where the DW feet go.  My wife and I are both tall and when we built our house we decided on a 39" counter height, meaning we had to build up for the range and dishwashers. Worked fine. It also means not having to bend over the dishwasher as far to load and unload it, nice.

So IMHO shim/build up as needed under the DW, I think it would look odd to make up that much space above it.

Comment: OP would also need to create some kind of finish panel for the kick area, since the stock finish panel will now be 3.5-ish inches above the floor.

Comment: I agree, then get a toe kick and attach it to the ends of the 2x4's to finish off the install. +

Comment: We just cut down a piece of toe kick trim and extended it under the panel that came with the DW.  You still want to retain that panel to give access for electrical (if hard wired) and plumbing connections.

Answer (score 5):

Every dishwasher I've ever installed has adjustable feet so that you can raise/lower and level it in the opening.

If yours doesn't have that, you'll need to shim under the feet to get it level and to the correct height.

If there isn't enough adjustment in the feet or it takes too many shims, you can also get a spacer for the top of the opening from the cabinet dealer that will help fill the space.  Generally, you should be able to get a piece of finished 1x that will match your cabinets exactly.

The installation manual should have the appropriate instructions.

Comment: EVERY dishwasher I ever installed had adjustment at the bottom, in some cases a lot.. If it were me I would run it up all the way and if there was any lacking at the top, I would add a filler at the top, hopefully no more than a 1 1/2" or less. I would be thoroughly surprised if it did not go up to 34 1/2"+ with the adjustable feet.....+1